# Simple Hook Menu not doing what it is supposed to do

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

If a user is logged in as admin, it works fine but if user is logged in, it is sending them their profile page. Why?. What files can I check?

```
$items['go/to/school'] = array(
  'title' => 'Some page Title',
  'page callback' => 'my_function',
  'access callback' => 'my_access',
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);

function my_function() {
  echo "WHATS UP"; //NEVER SHOWS UP
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your callback `function myaccess()` must return TRUE for that user, else that user has no access. This callback function can get arguments trough `access arguments`. When you do not provide the `access callback` it defaults to `function user_access($access_string)`, in which case you still need to provide `access arguments`, e.g. "access content".

Also note, that after each change in the hook_menu-code you must refresh the menu-cache, since this is cached quit heavily.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like this page to be visible to all users (logged-in or anonymous), the simplest way is to just return TRUE in your access callback. For example:

```
'access callback' => TRUE,
```

Otherwise, like berkes said, your access callback must return TRUE for that user to see the page. For example:

```
function my_access() {
  global $user;
  return in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles);
}
```

This will return TRUE if the user has a role of "authenticated user" and FALSE if they do not.